# Electric potential diverging at $x = 0$

Tags: electrostatics, potential, voltage, singularities

I am sure this basic question has already been answered countless times but I just can't seem to find a satisfactory answer on the web.

Assume we have an electric charge at the point x = 0. Then, the electric potential $\Phi$ would have the form of $\frac{1}{|x|}$. The voltage is given as the difference in electric potential between two points A and B.

Let's say we take B at $x = \infty$ as a reference point for $\Phi = 0$. If someone was to ask me what the voltage at the point A at x = 0 is, how would I compute the potential difference since $\Phi$ goes to infinity at x = 0? One couldn't just write $\Phi_2 - \Phi_1 = V$ since $\Phi_2 = 0$ and $\Phi_1 = \infty$.

In other words, how is the voltage computed for a given point, when electric charges are placed exactly at that point (and thus the electric potential diverges)?

P.S.: I am mostly looking for an intuition for this type of problem of diverging electric potential in general. (same issue for capacitor plates for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At small enough scales, modeling any charge as a 1D 'point charge' breaks down.

One option is to model the object a sphere of radius R (bonus points if it is a sphere) and use the maximum voltage as $V(R) = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 R} $ (and/or with some arbitrary constant).

If you're really worried about the behavior around $r=0$ you'll want to use a quantum mechanics approach

Comment: So for calculations such as the capacitance, or the voltage at a given point in an electric circuit, one has to assume a charge density distribution instead of points and use workaround equations?

Comment: @Leizi Capacitors and wires are 3D objects, so there is no divergence to worry about. For capacitor plates, for example, you model them as infinite sheets of charge to calculate the voltage difference.  This works well as long as the distance between the plates is small relative to the size of the plates.